# ASP.NET Core Attribute Routing bug?

Tags: routes, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

All of my routes in ASP.NET Core 3.1 work fine, except this empty one.

I should be able to hit this route:

- `/Document/HB89Letter` and hit the `Show` page
- `/Document/HB89Letter/Show` works
- `/Document/HB89Letter/` does not

This is my code:

```
[Route("Document/HB89Letter")]
[Authorize]
public class HB89LetterController : MacController
{
    [Route("")]
    [Route("Show")]
    public ActionResult Show(HB89LetterViewModel vm)
    {
        // some code
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, as per your expectation what `/Document/HB89Letter/` this should return? As per `route defination` it should return the related `view page` as it is `MVC` controller. Not sure what you are expecting here.

Comment: In addtion, could you please share your `startup.cs` file hows your `routes.MapRoute` `template` looks like?

Comment: When you use Route("") on a method that means when navigate to www.site.com/Document/Hb89Letter you should be taken to that method.

Comment: I do not have any routes defined in startup.  All routes are attribute based.

Comment: I am sorry I posted this question.  Turns out I had a conflict in my base controller that created ambiguity in the route.

Comment: Thanks for the update, It seems that your problem has been resolved as I have tried your route and successfully hit that without any trouble. Let me know if you still need any further assistance on this.